# Microclimates of Peaks of Eternal Light on a Earth Like Planet

Tags: earth-like, climate, axial-tilt

[Peaks of Eternal Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_of_eternal_light) are hypothetical mountain peaks that exist on the poles of worlds with little to no axial tilt. My question is simply, if such a peak *did* exist on an earth-like planet, one with no moon or axial tilt obviously, what kind of microclimates might exist on this peak? Not taking the atmosphere into account, I would almost think it would be a high-altitude hot desert in the middle of a sea of ice, but I suspect this would not be the case.

Answer (score 9):

On Earth, the planet's axial tilt means that the poles spend at least some of each year in permanent sunlight during their summer. This warms them up, certainly, but I wouldn't go as far as to say it was *hot* by any stretch of the imagination (unless you have the imagination of a polar bear, in which case it might seem a bit uncomfortably warm). At least part of the warmth comes from having the sun (relatively) high in the sky, and it illuminating quite a wide area.

For peaks of eternal light, the sun will be just peeking over the horizon, giving a sort of perpetual twilight. They'll be a little peak of *relative* warmth (or at least, "less frigidity") in a vast frozen wasteland, but they'll still be high altitude mountains in gloomy light. They'll be bitterly cold, and probably very dry, like a less cheerful version of antarctica's dry valleys.

Comment: They would be warmer if the planet would closer to its star. That would of course imply that the most of the planet is inhospitably hot, making non-polar regions hellish.